# SAP GUI how to find findById

Tags: python-3.x, sap-gui

I would like to automate via SAP GUI Scripting. Former I used the SAP GUI tracker to record all my task. However, the tool is not working any longer on Win10.

Is there a way to find - native in the SAP GUI - the `findById` object names? I'm using SAP GUI 7.5.

Thank you very much in advance and best regards

Andi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the official SAP solutions:

1. SAP GUI Recorder (it generates a VBScript file with all your actions, and it contains the IDs of the fields you have modified):

   [image]
2. `screenreader.exe` program ("SAP GUI Scripting Spy") provided by SAP to display the IDs by pointing the fields with the mouse cursor (in [note 1441550 - SAP GUI scripting: Sample applications](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1441550/E))

   [image]
3. You may also write your own VBScript tool because SAP GUI Scripting implements the features of the Script Recording tool and the Scripting Spy --and even more-- :

   - Display the red box around the focused field and do something when a field is hit: property `ElementVisualizationMode` of object [GuiFrameWindow](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.02/en-US?q=GuiFrameWindow)  Event `Hit` of object [GuiSession](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.02/en-US?q=GuiSession)
   - Your custom recording: method `Record` and event `Change` of object [GuiSession](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.02/en-US?q=GuiSession)
   - Standard Script Recording: method `RecordFile` of object [GuiSession](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.02/en-US?q=GuiSession)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! You made my day!